What keeps modifying my /etc/group?
I am trying to add my user to several groups. I used sudo usermod -G group1,group2 to add my user to the supplemental groups I had created myself. My username shows up in /etc/group then. However after reboot they are gone. The groups remain in /etc/group but my username is removed. Furthermore id yields a supplemental group (let's name it group3). In /etc/group I'm not a member of it. Grepping over etc yielded files named /etc/group- and /etc/gshadow- containing my membership of group3.
What's /etc/group- and why are my supplemental group memberships removed from /etc/group after reboot?
I am using Void Linux, and:
$ uname -a 
Linux ojiisan 6.6.52_1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Sep 21 15:47:36 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The GUI is Gnome.
[ariser@ojiisan ~]$ grep group /etc/nsswitch.conf
group:      files


/etc/group- is the backup before the latest modification.  It might be relevant to know how you are logging in.  You might try logging in on a text console as root and see if things have changed, as it might be something other than the reboot that makes the change.

Does sudo usermod -aG group1,group2 work better? You need the -a if you just want to add groups your user belongs to, not reset group membership. That doesn't explain why it doesn't survive a reboot though.

Please provide the output of grep group /etc/nsswitch.conf (in your question)

@terdon nailed it. The error sat in front of the computer, again. I added my groups not all at once, and some I added later on, so I always cleared my supplemental groups and wondered about single ones left in the backups. Now after testing and rebooting several times, everything makes sense!

The loss of groups after reboot was an artifact in my brain, because I always tried reboots after doing modifications without properly checking the outcome of the modifications first.

Ah, great! If you can, please post an answer explaining what you did.

Very likely when you created the group you accidentally reused a group ID that was already in use by "group3".  Not sure why your username would be removed from the line in /etc/group but system tools that recognize groups will see the first group using the id in /etc/group not your addition.
Another possibility is that the file /etc/group is actually read only and changes to it were only saved in memory and not written to disk.  This could occur for instance if you are using an SD card and the SD card is failing.  It could also happen if the group file is dynamically generated by the system at boot.  However, a quick check this does not seem to be the case for Void linux.  Neither of these causes are likely; more likely you have misinterpreted what changes were made to /etc/group in the first place.

Thank you, your answer barked up the right tree even if the problem sat on another twig. So it helped me to put things together. I unwillingly overwrote my groups several times, because I omitted the -a option.
